# Finding the adress of file knowing the name in C

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu, cd, chdir

I am writing my own shell in C/Ubuntu for a project but I had some diffuculties when using `chdir()` to implement `cd`. `chdir()` needs a path name but since the user will write (lets assume) `cd Desktop`, `Desktop` is not a path name so the program will fail.

Here is that part of my code:

```
child = fork();
if (child == 0) {
    if (!strcmp(args[0], "ls")) {
        execv("/bin/ls", args);
    }
    if (!strcmp(args[0] , "cd")) {
        chdir(args[1]);
    }  
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);  //Failure
} else {
    do {
       waitpid(child, &status, WUNTRACED);
} while(!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
```

So I think the problem is that `args[1]` gets things like `"Desktop"` etc instead of the address so `chdir` fails. I tested it in terminal, all other commands work except `cd`. My question is that how can I make this `chdir` work?In another words how can I give the path of `args[1]` to `chdir`?

Let me put it in this way. When I write `cd Desktop` to terminal it works. When I write `cd Desktop` to my own shell it tries to execute `chdir("Desktop")` and it fails.

Comment: If Desktop is not a pathname, then what is it and how do you expect to change directory into it?

Comment: Let me put it in this way.When I write cd Desktop to terminal it works.When I write cd Desktop to my own shell it tries to execute chdir(Desktop)and it fails

Comment: Does a directory called Desktop exist inside the current directory?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of directories, how you can have different directories below each other in a hierarchy and how a process has a current directory? If "cd Desktop" works from your terminal but not your own shell it might be because your own shell has another current directory.

Comment: It might also be interesting to look at the value of errno if chdir fails. If the return value of chdir is something else than 0 perror might be a nice function to call.

Comment: `Desktop` might be a special name recognized by the shell, what system are running?  Does your `cd` command work for other directories?

Comment: How do you know, that `chdir` fails? You didn't checked the return value. And yes, this function returns to the caller  (in opposition to `exec`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use use `exec` to run the `ls` command, I suspect you `fork()` the process before selecting which command to execute: `chdir(args[1])` is executed in the child process, the child process changes its current directory and then exits. Each process has its own current directory. The parent (shell) process current directory in unaffected by the change in its child, it keeps its current directory.

Most command should be executed in the shell process without forking, only external commands should be executed after forking to a child process.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
/* frist execute local commands in the shell process. */
if (!strcmp(args[0], "cd")) {
    if (!args[1]) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cd: missing argument\n");
    } else
    if (chdir(args[1])) {
        perror("chdir");
    }
} else
if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit")) {
    int status = args[1] ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;
    exit(status);
} else {
    /* otherwise, fork and attempt to execute an external command */
    child = fork();
    if (child == 0) {
        if (!strcmp(args[0], "ls")) {
            execv("/bin/ls", args);
        }
        /* if exec failed, the child process is still running */
        perror("exec");
        exit(1);  //Failure
    } else {
        do {
           waitpid(child, &status, WUNTRACED);
    } while(!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
}
```

Comment: I am forking to run chdir.I am updating the code right now

Comment: @JonathanPark: that's what I was guessing.  Only `fork()` to `exec()` external commands.

Comment: I understood you.When I run my code on terminal if I try to use cd Desktop it gives me an error and stays in my shell.When I am in terminal using original shell when I write cd Desktop it moves into Desktop.So I need to make my cd command like that but I could not figure it out.Hope this code will help someone to figure it out

Comment: @JonathanPark: you observe this because of another error: after `chdir()`, you call `perror()` and `exit(1)`. You should call `perror` only if the command failed, which is implicit for `exec`, but not for `chdir()`.

Comment: I solved it slightly differently but your code seems better.I am accepting it as an answer thank you.Exit was already in there in my code I did not post it since it was not related with this question

Comment: @JonathanPark: Thank you, I only added `exit()` as an example of another local shell command.